# Probability distribution for a function of a random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, parametric

I have the distribution of X with respect to parameter t vaying between 0 and 1. However, in nature, parameter t is not uniformly distributed. It has a known probability distribution. What is distribution of X given distribution of t? The product? Can you clarify, and hint at notions or concepts involved?

EDIT: in fact, problem can be formulated this way: X is a function of t,

$X: t  -> X(t)$

and I would like to have an expression for P(X(t)) when I known the distribution for t.

Thanks

Comment: How can the distributions of $t$ and $X$ be independent when the distribution of $X$ depends on $t$?

Comment: I mean that distribution for parameter t is independent of distribution for X ^^

Comment: That still doesn't make sense. Independence is symmetric.

Comment: Thats right, its not independent. X's distribution is a function of parameter t (which is known). And t has a known probability distribution. Question remains: what is then distribution of X knowing distribution of t?

Comment: The distribution of $X$ could be anything. As Tunoco rightly points out, it is in general dependent upon $t$. But special cases could have no such dependency. Take $X:t \mapsto 1$ for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let t have density f and let x=g(t). If g is 1-1 the t=g$^-$$^1$(x). Substitute g$^-$$^1$(x) for t in f and then multiply by the Jacobian of the transformation to get the density for x.